# Concurrent workflows in Github actions

Tags: automation, github-actions, workflow

I have a workflow "Run Script". I want to prevent running more than 1 instance of my workflow. If I trigger "Run Script" 5 times at the same time. Only 1 job shows pending, other pending jobs are getting cancelled.

Error Message: `Canceling since a higher priority waiting request for 'my-concurrency-group' exists`

Here's any example worklow file

```
name: Run Script

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  
concurrency:
  group: my-concurrency-group
  cancel-in-progress: false
  
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Installing python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.9'
          cache: 'pip'
```

Comment: Using `concurrency` already results in only ever one workflow in the same concurrency group running at the same time; the difference between `cancel-in-progress` being `true` or `false` is whether a currently running workflow gets cancelled or not. It's not clear to me how the behaviour you see isn't what you want.

Comment: What is your expected behavior @ujjwal? Cancelling the workflow run in-progress to start the new one?